# Whats wrong with the following sqlite statement in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

What is wrong with the following code? I get the following error

**unrecognized token: "12345" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, flag FROM myTable WHERE snumber=12345**

```
String number = "12345";    
public static final String SNUMBER = "snumber";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final  String FLAG = "flag";

String[] thecolumns = new String[] { ID, FLAG };

Cursor cursor = sqlDb.query(TABLE_NAME , thecolumns, SNUMBER+ "=" + number, null, null,   null, null);
```

Comment: Please format errors as code, rather than bolding, and give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can understand what you're doing.

Comment: You've got minimal part covered.  It's a simple value quoting problem, no need to include a whole android app in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Cursor cursor = sqlDb.query(TABLE_NAME , thecolumns, SNUMBER+ "='" + number+"', null, null,   null, null);
```

I added `''` around `number`

Comment: Thanks worked .. never knew that there was a quote over there.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your data. using "?" for params is great. And you need to cast it to a String. Common way doing this when not using rawQuery is:

```
  Cursor cursor = sqlDb.query(TABLE_NAME , thecolumns, SNUMBER+ "=?", Integer.toString(number), null,   null, null);
```